# Combining SUM from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have the below 2 MYSQL weekly tables:

TableA_Wk1

```
Id | Price
----------
1  | 1
1  | 2
2  | 5
```

TableA_Wk2

```
Id | Price
----------
1  | 2
4  | 2
```

I can group the price in one table:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Price) FROM TableA_Wk1
GROUP BY Id
```

and get

```
Id | Price
----------
1  | 3
2  | 5
```

I would like to also consider the table TableA_Wk2 to get the below:

```
Id | Price
----------
1  | 5
2  | 5
4  | 2
```

If i use UNION ALL the result is separated:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Price) FROM TableA_Wk1
  GROUP BY Id
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, SUM(Price) FROM TableA_Wk2
  GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the `<Id,price>` tuples from those two tables. Then Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY Id` on the resultant table.

```
SELECT 
t.Id,
SUM(t.price) 
FROM 
(
 SELECT Id, Price FROM TableA_Wk1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Id, Price FROM TableA_Wk2
) AS t
GROUP BY t.Id
```

**Note**

`UNION` removes duplicates.

`UNION ALL` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Union the result set and then perform summation to get the summed value.

```
select sum(price) from (
   select price from TableA_Wk1
   union all  
   select price from TableA_Wk1
) as alais
```

Answer (score 1):

First `UNION` , then `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT t.id,sum(t.price) as price
FROM (
      SELECT id,price from TableA_Wk1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id,price from TableA_Wk2
     ) t
GROUP BY t.id
```